# Wait for the Bloc to finish in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
Future<void> loginWithEmail(
  String email,
  String password,
) async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  final data = await request('fetch-user');
  final user = UserV1.fromJson(data);
  userBloc.add(UpdateUserAction(user));

  fetchAllLogs();
  requestPushNotifications();
  resetMuscleFreshnessOnLogin();
  await fetchUserLights([user.uid]);
  await fetchExercises();
  // Must be after fetch exercises
  generateNextWorkout();
  return;
}
```

In the following code I need to wait for the **userBloc** to finish. But not sure how to do this. Using the FlutterBloc lib.

It would be nice if I could do

```
await userBloc.add(UpdateUserAction(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

The suction is simple.

```
await userBloc.first;
```